# Need help on Pie Chart transition on taking DATA from mouse hover to a STATE of the Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I need some help about D3js about connecting data.

here is the one iam working on::

http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/16/

The value should be taken only from the state that the mouse hover for generating PIE chart . but i am facing some difficulty in taking the DATA
from the mouse hover, Any help would be appreciated.

```
dataSet = [
  {
    "label": "Assault on women ",
    "value": 64131,
    "color": "#1ee675"
  },
  {
    "label": "Dowry Deaths",
    "value": 57618,
    "color": "#44b9ae"
  },
  {
    "label": "Cruelty",
    "value": 18812,
    "color": "#7b37c0"
  },

  {
    "label": "Dowry Prohibition Act",
    "value": 114384,
    "color": "#bca349"
  },
  {
    "label": "Immoral Traffic (P) Act",
    "value": 67706,
    "color": "#8b6834"
  },
  {
    "label": "Importation of Girls",
    "value": 36344,
    "color": "#cc9fb0"
  },

  {
    "label": "Kidnapping and Abduction",
    "value": 36344,
    "color": "#cc9fb0"
  },
  {
    "label": "Total Crimes against Women",
    "value": 36344,
    "color": "#cc9fb0"
  },

  {
    "label": "INSULT TO MODEST",
    "value": 32170,
    "color": "#7c9058"
  }
];
```

Here is one of the example I have look on:
http://simonbjohnson.github.io/Ebola_Dashboard/

[image: Map Hover Line chart Generate]